# Python/django os.mkdir() fails in OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR subfolder

Tags: python, django, openshift, permission-denied

I've a code that uploads user provided attachments in a Openshift hosted django app. But the upload code always fails showing the following stacktrace :

```
Traceback:
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/acubor/voucher/views.py" in save_vch
  267.     voucher = save_model(voucher, voucher_values)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/acubor/lib.py" in save_model
  108.     model.save()
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  650.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  215.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1675.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  936.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  894.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  250.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  48.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  171.                 os.makedirs(directory)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  150.             makedirs(head, mode)
File "/var/lib/openshift/some_hash_value/python//virtenv/lib64/python2.7/os.py" in makedirs
  157.     mkdir(name, mode)
Exception Type: OSError at /voucher/journal/save/
Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users'
Request information:
GET: No GET data
```

And the relevant settings are :

```
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'), 'user-uploads')
    MEDIA_URL = '/user-uploads/'
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: you need to change the folder permissions

Comment: of which folder and what permissions should I assign ?

Comment: have you `/Users` folder ?

Comment: @dhana OP is using Openshift, so don't worry about folder permissions

Comment: @abhayK You need to create the directory `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/user-uploads`. To achieve that, you need to create a action hook, the last part of this blog would help: http://masci.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/serving-django-media-files-in-openshift/

Comment: Actually it was the result of messed up settings. Unknowingly I've been assigning a local machine's address to MEDIA_ROOT. Corrected that and the upload is working. Now Serving the uploaded files back seems a bit tricky. Will follow the post suggested by @Leonardo.Z